# Recreating a grayscale cutout effect on an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, image-editing

I am trying to recreate this image from a standard photo of the dog, but struggling to get it to look like the edited image. What filters or adjustments might have been used to create this?

Original Photograph of the dog:

[image]

The effect I am trying to recreate:

[image]

Comment: added the original too, if anyone wants to give it a go. think I am definitely at my wits end!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me more like an Image Trace from Illustrator than a Cutout effect from Photoshop. The result is similar, but you have more control over the paths with an Image Trace and Image Trace produces curved paths whereas a Cutout gives you hard edges and corners.

See this quick Image Trace:

[image]

The "textured" look in your example actually looks to me just to be JPG artefacts, but if you want to achieve something similar you can bring the traced image back in to Photoshop (or rasterize and do so directly in Illustrator) and apply a Dry Brush effect:

<sup>It's hard to see the details at this size; open the image at full size to better see the effect.</sup>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this routine:

1. Image → Mode → Grayscale
2. Image → Posterise (set at three to five shades)
3. Filter → Noise → Median (adjust the slider to fine tune the effect)

Comment: thanks for the idea, I have tried it, but think there might be some brush stroke overlay or something, never really worked with filters etc. before and didn't realise how difficult it is to recreate something like that!